# Postgresql running sum of previous groups?

Tags: postgresql, grouping, window-functions

Given the following data:

```
sequence | amount
1          100000
1          20000
2          10000
2          10000
```

I'd like to write a sql query that gives me the sum of the current sequence, plus the sum of the previous sequence.  Like so:

```
sequence | current | previous
1 120000 0
2 20000 120000
```

I know the solution likely involves windowing functions but I'm not too sure how to implement it without subqueries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9e9d9/1)

```
select
    seq,
    amount,
    lag(amount::int, 1, 0) over(order by seq) as previous
from (
    select seq, sum(amount) as amount
    from sa
    group by seq
) s
order by seq
```

Comment: It's that lag feature that I could find properly documented here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-window.html.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: what are the other options to lag, and what specifically is lag doing there?  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, re-reading the docs for lag makes it clear now.  Thanks again!

Comment: +1 for nice formaitting and lowercase keywords, I really hate UPPERCASE SQL statements, it's like we're still in 1980..

Answer (score 0):

If your sequence is "sequencial" without holes you can simply do:

```
SELECT t1.sequence,
  SUM(t1.amount),
  (SELECT SUM(t2.amount) from mytable t2 WHERE t2.sequence = t1.sequence - 1)
FROM mytable t1
GROUP BY t1.sequence
ORDER BY t1.sequence
```

Otherwise, instead of `t2.sequence = t1.sequence - 1` you could do:

```
SELECT t1.sequence,
  SUM(t1.amount),
  (SELECT SUM(t2.amount) 
   from mytable t2 
   WHERE t2.sequence = (SELECT MAX(t3.sequence) 
                        FROM mytable t3 
                        WHERE t3.sequence < t1.sequence))
FROM mytable t1
GROUP BY t1.sequence
ORDER BY t1.sequence;
```

You can see both approaches in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/821b8/6)